# Matlab : Pan a figure programmatically

Tags: matlab, figure, pan

I've been plotting some figures and I want to save them multiple times zoomed in certain areas. All my views have pivot-point at y=0 except one, the last view. I've been using 'XLim' to change the view on the X axis. Now I need to pan the view on the Y axis. When using YLim, the aspect ratio of the image changes.

Is it possible to set some pivot point on the Y-axis?

Here is a minimum working code where my problem can be seen. Pauses 2 times.

```
f1 = figure(10);
hold on
axis equal
x = linspace(1,2*pi);
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y,'*')
xlims=[0 2*pi; 1 2*pi; 0.5 1.5];

for i = 1:size(xlims,1)
    set(gca,'XLim',xlims(i,:))
    disp('Here I am saving this view! (Paused)')
    pause
end

% Now I want to PAN the Y axis and set the view around Y = 1.
% But still keep last set Xlims AND keep the aspect ratio of figure.
% When using YLim, the aspect ratio changes.

set(gca,'YLim',[0.9 1.1]) % Not what I have in mind.
% Just need to pivot Y=1...
```

Comment: What's wrong with `set(gca, 'YLim', get(gca, 'YLim')+dy)`?

Comment: This works just perfectly! Thank you so much... Why didn't I think of getting the current 'ylims' and change and add the change of y.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "panning" command as such. (there is a `pan` command but this just toggles the ability to pan using the mouse on or off).

But, there is the ability to set your axis limits dictating which portion of the plot to show, using the `axis` function, with manually specified limits.

e.g. `axis([ xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax ]);`

Furthermore, if you apply this after any other `axis` calls that affect shape / aspect ratio (e.g. `axis square` or `axis equal`) then these will be preserved.

Note that in your particular example, the use of `axis equal` therefore necessarily means that for a smaller range of `Y` your aspect ratio will be smaller. Therefore you might to opt against that.

Alternatively, you can also control the aspect ratio manually with the `daspect` function. e.g., in your example:

```
>> axis equal  % your initial axis / aspect ratio situation
>> A = axis;
>> axis([0.5,1.5,0.9,1.1]); % your new values. aspect ratio will change to preserve equality
>> B = axis;
>> Y_factor = (A(4)-A(3))/(B(4)-B(3));
>> daspect([Y_factor, 1, 1]);  % back to the old "aspect ratio"
```

However, this clearly means that the two axes are now not "equal", and the comparison with previous graphs might be misleading. This may or may not be a factor to take into consideration.

Finally, if what you're really after is simply to make sure your axes object does not change size, you can simply set the size of your axes object manually (e.g. `set(gca, 'position', [x,y,x_width, y_width])` )  and ensure axis is on `normal` mode (i.e. adapting to the axes size).

Answer (score 0):

The answer given in a comment by @jodag is perfect. Since comments have a tendency to disappear I thought I would reproduce it here.

To "pan", you need to change both limits without changing their interval. Since you can read the current interval with

```
get(gca, 'YLim')
```

you can simply pan the y axis by a distance `dy` with the command:

```
set(gca, 'YLim', get(gca, 'YLim')+dy)
```